# Как сделать https сервер на ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, delphi, https, openssl, indy

В **Delphi 11** на **windows** создаю сервер с помощью **Indy** и компилирую на **Ubuntu server** с установленным **openssl-3.1.0**

```
IdHTTPServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
IdHTTPServer.DefaultPort := 9875;
IdHTTPServer.IOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTPServer);
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'root.pem';
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.CertFile := 'cert.pem';
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'key.pem';
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.CipherList := 'ALL';
(IdHTTPServer.IOHandler AS TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := fuGetSSLVersions;
IdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet := IdHTTPServerOnCommandGet;
IdHTTPServer.Active := True;
```

Если обращаюсь к серверу http://host:9875/, ответ приходит,
а как только пробую httpS://host:9875/ , ответа нет.

Подскажите, может я что то забыл, почему не работает?

Comment: [Behavioral change to HTTPS handling in TIdHTTPServer](https://www.indyproject.org/2018/05/30/behavioral-change-to-https-handling-in-tidhttpserver/)

Comment: И Indy официально поддерживает пока только OpenSSL 1.0.2. Поддержка новых версий ещё не [принята](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299), но по словам инициатора [код](https://github.com/mezen/Indy/tree/NewOpenSSL_PR) вполне работоспособен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zed спасибо, помогло.

```
constructor THttpServer.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  IdHTTPServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  ...
  IdHTTPServer.OnQuerySSLPort := IdHTTPServerOnQuerySSLPort;
  ...
end;

procedure THttpServer.IdHTTPServerOnQuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var VUseSSL: Boolean);
begin
  if APort = 9876 then VUseSSL := False
  else if APort = 9875 then VUseSSL := True;
end;
```